# Simulating nested params in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, tdd, bdd

I need simulate sending params in test, same as these inputs would send:

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantities[9671]" type="number" value="1" />
<input id="quantity" name="quantities[9822]" type="number" value="1" />
```

Test looks like this: (using Test Unit, the default testing framework in Rails):

```
test "placing item into basket"
  cart = Cart.new(session)

  post :create,
    product_variant_ids: [@product.variants.first.id],
    "quantities[#{@product.variants.first.id}]" => 1 # <<<------ not working 

  assert_equal 1, cart.items.count
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the input param as :

```
"quantities[123]" => 1
```

you will have to access it later at your controller by using :

```
params["quantities[123]"]
```

---

Normally an input like :

```
<input id="quantity" name="quantities[9671]" type="number" value="1" />
```

will be available in your params as a nested hash. For the above case it will be then like :

```
params["quantities"]["9671"]
```

---

So in your case it should work if you pass it like this :

```
quantities: {@product.variants.first.id => 1}
```